# Is `meson.source_root()` the project root directory?

Tags: build, build-system, meson-build

Is the directory return by meson.source_root() the project root directory (with the root level meson.build file) or is it the path of the current meson.build file being processed?

Answer (score 7):

The project root directory is obtained with the following meson syntax:

```
meson.source_root()
```

The current source directory can be obtained with the following meson syntax:

```
meson.current_source_dir()
```

Comment: Something "disturbing" is that current_source_dir() gives a relative path to the source_root(), so I always need to do `join_paths(meson.source_root(), meson.current_source_dir())`.

Comment: @slamander I just tried what you suggested and it didn't work for me. It's possible we're talking about different things, but if have source root `/some/dir` and current source dir `some/dir/src` then `current_source_dir()` gives me `/some/dir/./src` and join_paths() as you show above gives me the same thing. I  did the following to fix this, but there may be a better/easier way (it's my first day with meson):    `curDir = meson.current_source_dir()` 
 `curDir = curDir.split('.')`  `curDir = curDir[0] + curDir[1]`  `curDir = curDir.split('//')`  `curDir = join_paths(curDir[0], curDir[1])`

Comment: Ran out of space in my previous comment, but the code I provided there is brittle if you have dirtectory names that contain '.' characters. What I did was to encose everything after the `curDir = meson.current_source_dir()` in `if ( curDir.contains('/./') )` to ensure it doesn't execute on random '.' chars.

Comment: Please mention that `source_root()` is deprecated in preference of *(depending on what you want)*: `current_source_dir()`, `project_source_root()`, or `global_source_root()`.